# Couldn't set refs/heads/master when commit

Tags: git, git-commit

I was able to commit fine yesterday. But today (I didn't change anything), when I commit:

```
$ git add config.h
$ git commit -m "Update config.h to reset the values"
error: Couldn't set refs/heads/master
fatal: cannot update HEAD ref
```

I know that this error may happen also during pull or push. But I haven't found a solution to fix it when committing.

My .git/config file looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@SOME_URL
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems you have lost your `HEAD`, so you will have to recreate it. You can do that using this.

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

This will create a `HEAD` file in your .git folder. That should solve your problem.

Also, try the `git fsck` command. It verifies the connectivity and validity of the objects in the database.

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

Use this to scan for unreachable objects. It will write dangling objects into `.git/lost-found/commit/` or `.git/lost-found/other/`, depending on type. If the object is a blob, the contents are written into the file, rather than its object name.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it but this doesn't solve the problem. I have the HEAD file

Comment: "It seems you have lost your HEAD" statement of the day ;)

Answer (score 11):

I experienced this problem (`fatal: couldn't set 'refs/heads/my-branch'`) when I had 2 copies of VS Code, each with integrated terminals checked out to the same commit. Except one version of VS Code was in WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux) mode. I closed the WSL VS Code and immediately was able to commit in the vanilla non-WSL VS Code.

Answer (score 5):

This may help others; I waited about a minute and simply retried the commit and ... it worked.

Comment: Worked for me too. I was rebasing on the command line and `eclipse` had something locked. Closed eclipse and `git rebase --continue` worked.

Comment: I think for me it was Dropbox; this solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was with **permission on the GIT repository on server** for the path `refs/Heads/master`.

> After allowing my username for accessing the mentioned path, all worked well.

Answer (score 2):

For me it took a Windows reboot to get it working again :-)))

Comment: same, tried lot of things but they didn't work until I restarted Windows

Answer (score 1):

Check your .git folder for file HEAD.

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

If this does not exist, create it.

```
$ echo "ref: refs/Heads/master" > .git/HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it but this doesn't solve the problem. I do have the .git/HEAD file

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in my `.git` folder, there was file `HEAD`, and it couldn't rename `HEAD.lock` to `HEAD` (even though it didn't tell me). I removed the `HEAD` file, and it was able to work fine.

(I was also using TortoiseGit; don't know if that had anything to do with it)